# C# lock internal implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I know that now in `C#` `lock` is implemented in such way:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try 
{ 
     Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken); 
     { 
        //body 
     } 
}
finally 
{ 
     if (lockWasTaken) 
     {
         Monitor.Exit(temp); 
      }
}
```

Why do we need this: `var temp = obj;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, What if you changed the variable after the `Monitor.Enter` called and before `Monitor.Exit`?

To prevent that it takes up a copy of the variable. Even you can set the value to `null` also inside the `lock` statement but still it makes sure that it releases the lock which it taken earlier.

Comment: @BransDs - but `obj = SomeOtherObject()` is valid code to appear inside the body of the lock.

Comment: @BransDs  What do you meant by that? assigning will change the copy. so after you reassigning temp and obj will be pointing to different things, try it out

Answer (score 1):

Because `obj` might be reassigned within the body of the lock code, and the code you've shown has to make sure that it calls `Exit` on the *same* object it called `Enter` for.